# SparkR and Sparklyr in R version

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr

Previously, I use the sparklyr packages within R which is very successful to run with a lot of functions with spark version 2.2.0 . Yesterday, I installed the package called SparkR and I accidentally installed the spark version 2.1.2 . Then the problem came, in this situation, I can not transfer the sparkR into sparklyr anymore. for instance, it will give you this type of error:

```
spark_install(version = "2.2.0")
```

> Error in if (is.na(a)) return(-1L) : argument is of length zero

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
```

> Error in if (is.na(a)) return(-1L) : argument is of length zero

```
spark_uninstall()
```

> Error in if (is.na(a)) return(-1L) : argument is of length zero

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: maybe you could uninstall spark manually: http://macuninstallguides.com/remove-spark-2-1-0-426-on-mac.html and then reinstall 2.2.0

Comment: The method is that the mess between sparkR and sparklyr. It is in some hidden folder in the server which should be manually removed.